# How to copy field data and use it in another field of same document using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have two fields in my User Scehma , cart and orders both are array.

[image: fields]

I want to copy all the items in cart array to orders array and then remove/delete all the items in my cart array. How do I that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use update `$set` with `$concatArrays`

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      orders: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$orders",
          "$carts"
        ]
      },
      carts: []
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1EI7vb_Foii)

Comment: the query for selecting that particular document will go in,  the {} after update, right?